# Bootstrap responsive layout issue

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I am using the bootstrap latest version for my website, I have some issue coding the layout of my page into following image
[image]

Comment: So, what is your question? Also, could you show what you've already got?

Comment: For large screens it is working properly but when it comes to small devices and extra small devices, the block 2 come after block 4, order is 1,3,4,2,5. I want in 1,2,3,4,5 order.

Comment: Please show us show us some code, so we can help you.

Comment: my crystal ball tells me your div id="ahsjhashkh" is overlapping div="khjaskhkh" because of jklhhjkhjkhjkh. But well, you know how reliable are crystal balls these days

Answer (score 0):

This could be a solution. Obviously the `id`s are for example.

```
<div class="container">
    <header>
        <div id="logo"></div>
    </header>
    <div id="background-image"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <div id="box1-with-3-columns" class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="box2-with-3-columns" class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="sign-up-box"></div>
    </div>
    <footer></footer>
</div>
```